# Samba giving me problems after restart

Tags: server, windows, mount, hard-drive, samba

I usually do not ask for much help as I google and research all my problems well. I am trying to share an internally attached hard drive through samba to access from (Android, Windows, and other Linux devices). I have successfully set up Samba to share the drive as a folder across the network and can view them promptly from each device, but when I restart I can not access the files UNTIL I open the drive via nautilus on the hosting Ubuntu computer. It's very weird and I have searched and searched and can not figure out the problem. Can anyone tip me on anything that may be the problem, maybe pertaining to mounting problems on boot?

Samba status shows running after restart without opening nautilus so Samba not running is not the problem.

Specs:

- Mobo: AMD E350M1
- OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- SSD: Sandisk 32GB
- HDD: Western Digital RED NAS 2 Terabyte Hard Drive as file storage